# PHP header returning Status 301 OK

Tags: php, http, redirect, header, http-status-codes

I have this simple PHP code running on a 64 bit linux server featuring PHP 5.4.40:

```
<?php
  header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
  header('Location: /folder');
  die();
?>
```

Any time I connect to this page I get a strange status code: 301 OK
I was unable to find where the problem is, hosting is a free plan *host-ed*, I don't have information about Apache version.

Thanks in advice

**EDIT**: Maybe I was not clear, I was expecting it to return *301 Moved Permanently*, not *301 OK* wich is against HTTP specs.

Comment: You've set a 301 code in the header and then wonder why you're seeing it? What sort of question is this?

Comment: You get the "301 OK" (which certainly is OK) but the redirect to /folder is not carried out ?

Comment: Location should be a valid path so that when the redirect happens you see the page you want.

Comment: Location is a valid path and the browser correctly redirects it, but it also complain that OK is not the right description for 301

Answer (score 0):

You are setting that 301 code with the following line:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
```